# Duplicate Google+ Page with same verified address

Tags: google-plus, google-account

I have one Google+ account with two pages, I own them. The two pages are verified at the same address. When I visit *Page Setting*, I can't remove the link to Google Maps for either page.

What can I do to merge them?

Answer (score 2):

You can contact Google team to resolve your issue via https://support.google.com/business/contactflow

```
Main menu > Business information & edits> My business appears on Maps twice
```

Comment: They call me twice by phone 48h later, it was merge two weeks later.